# Identically Keyed Topics Failing to Join in Kafka Streams

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I've recently encountered an issue within a streams application that I hadn't previously run into and it's been quite difficult to track down related to keying/joins (and after an update, partitioning).

**I have two topics (raw_events and processed_users), which are both keyed identically, but when I attempt to perform a join on the two topics, only *some* of the joins are successful, despite being keyed the same.**

## The Workflow (for context)

For brevity sake, the basic workflow of the application(s) are as follows:

1. Data flows into a `raw_event` topic via a Producer.
2. A series of streams applications listen to the `raw_event` topic and extract various entities from it based on a series of business rules (e.g. IP Addresses, Users, etc.)
3. Entities identified from the `raw_event` topic are placed into `preprocessing_{type}` topics, which contain metadata about the extraction and pertinent information that was found within the `raw_event` (e.g. for a user this might be things like an account name, e-mail, etc.). **Items in these topics are keyed by the `raw_event`.**
4. Another series of streams applications will listen to the various `preprocessing_{type}` topics and left join those against a series of GlobalKTables, which represent all of the known instances of that given entity `final_{type}`. For successful joins, the instance from `final_{type}` will be enriched using the new information from the `raw_event/preprocessing_{type}` topics; unsuccessful joins will indicate a new entity of a given type, which will then be keyed and placed into the `final_{type}` topic. **All enriched instances of `preprocessing_{type}` are inserted into a `processing_{type}` topic, which contains the enriched (or new) instance of the entity as well as the metadata that created it. Most importantly - items in the `processed_{type}` topic are keyed by the `raw_event` still.**
5. Finally, a streams application runs and attempts to enrich the original instance from `raw_event` by joining against the `processing_{type}`, which will be keyed the same, and enrich the `raw_event` instance with various information from the enriched entity, before pushing it to a `final_event` topic.

## The Issue

The issue itself is arising in Step 5. above (Event Enrichment) as only some of the joins between the `raw_event` topic and `processing_users` topic are working as expected.

**Using a subset of 24 records that went through the entire pipeline, only 5 of the 24 pairs in the topic joined successfully**. The ones that work appear to be the same consistent ones, but I don't see anything in the data that would indicate why one would work and the other would not:

```
raw_event keys          processing_user keys
mawjuG0B9k3AiALz0_2S    0q0juG0B9k3AiALz8ApP 
xEEcv20B9k3AiALzEN0m    m60juG0B9k3AiALz5gU5 
zqwjuG0B9k3AiALzz_tg    ua0juG0B9k3AiALz7wqa 
v60juG0B9k3AiALz6Aal    xEEcv20B9k3AiALzEN0m 
0q0juG0B9k3AiALz8ApP    zqwjuG0B9k3AiALzz_tg 
RK0juG0B9k3AiALz5QUw    zK0juG0B9k3AiALz6Aal
0a0juG0B9k3AiALz6Aal    Ta0juG0B9k3AiALz5QUw 
8KwjuG0B9k3AiALz1v58    RKwjuG0B9k3AiALz1P7C 
c60juG0B9k3AiALz5gU4    -60juG0B9k3AiALz3gGn 
RKwjuG0B9k3AiALz1P7C    Va0juG0B9k3AiALz5QUw 
zK0juG0B9k3AiALz6Aal    560juG0B9k3AiALz3QGh 
Ta0juG0B9k3AiALz5QUw    mawjuG0B9k3AiALz0_2S 
Va0juG0B9k3AiALz5QUw    -K0juG0B9k3AiALz3QGh 
pK0juG0B9k3AiALz5gU5    zq0juG0B9k3AiALz6Aal 
Xa0juG0B9k3AiALz2QCh    RK0juG0B9k3AiALz5QUw 
560juG0B9k3AiALz3QGh    v60juG0B9k3AiALz6Aal 
-K0juG0B9k3AiALz3QGh    Xa0juG0B9k3AiALz2QCh 
-60juG0B9k3AiALz3gGn    P60juG0B9k3AiALz5QUw 
F60juG0B9k3AiALz3gKn    pK0juG0B9k3AiALz5gU5 
m60juG0B9k3AiALz5gU5    0a0juG0B9k3AiALz6Aal 
zq0juG0B9k3AiALz6Aal    3K0juG0B9k3AiALz3QGh 
ua0juG0B9k3AiALz7wqa    8KwjuG0B9k3AiALz1v58 
3K0juG0B9k3AiALz3QGh    F60juG0B9k3AiALz3gKn 
P60juG0B9k3AiALz5QUw    c60juG0B9k3AiALz5gU4
```

I've tried combinations of joining the topics as both KStreams and KTables (and every combination that I can think of), however out of the 24 messages in this small subset, only ~5 of the joins are ever successful.

A current example (and slight simplification) of the current code:

```
val events = streams.createKTable<RawEvent>("raw_events)
val users = streams.createKStream<ProcessingUser>("processing_users)

val finalEvents = events
    .join(users, eventsProcessor::enrichWithUsers)
    .to("final_events")
```

Given that there are corresponding pairs (1:1) from the `raw_events` and `processing_users` topics, is there any explanation for why some of the joins would succeed and others would fail? Only 5 of the pairs will consistently make it through to the `final_events` topic (always the same pairs).

Any additional advice would be welcome!

## Configuration

For the sake of detail, here are a few things worth noting regarding the set-up:

- Using Kafka Streams 2.3.0
- Caching and Logging are enabled/disabled respectively for all applicable Materialized calls
- Topology Optimization is enabled
- Cache buffering is set to 0

## Update

The issue in a nutshell after spending a few hours mulling it over and digging into the data appears to be related to partitioning.

**The five joins that have been consistently succeeding, only appear to do so because the keys are located on the same partitions for each topic:**

```
successful events       raw_events partition  processing_users partition
RK0juG0B9k3AiALz5QUw    3                     3
m60juG0B9k3AiALz5gU5    7                     7
ua0juG0B9k3AiALz7wqa    7                     7
8KwjuG0B9k3AiALz1v58    8                     8
RKwjuG0B9k3AiALz1P7C    9                     9
```

Despite all of the keys being present in both topics, they don't appear to be partitioned using the same strategy (i.e. both topics *contain* all the messages with the same keys, but some may appear on one partition in `raw_events`, but a different partition in `processing_users`) as seen in this partition/count representation below:

[image]

It's worth reinforcing that the messages that appear within the `raw_events` topic are produced outside of the streams applications workflow that was described above, which leads me to believe that these questions will need to be answered:

- **Is is possible to allow the onus of the partitioning strategy to fall solely on the entry-point to the streams workflow assuming it results in a normalized distribution across partitions? (e.g. if a given key is in Partition 7 of `raw_events` and you send a record with the same key to `preprocessing_users`, it would fall into Partition 7?**
- **If so, is this a reasonable strategy? Or is there a way to enforce this behavior without writing a custom partitioner that is used by all producers and streams applications?**
- **If not, is it possible to take an existing topic (in this case `raw_event` and basically repartition the entire topic so that the default partitioning strategy is used?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As detailed in the updates to the original post, the issue itself was the result of a partitioning strategy discrepancy between the .NET Producer application, which by default uses the `consistent_random` partitioning strategy, as opposed to the default Java streams applications which use `murmur2random` strategy.

There are a few options to resolve this, but in this particular case, the easiest approach was to adjust the producer to use the appropriate strategy:

```
// Set the default partitioning strategy 
ProducerConfig.Partitioner = Partitioner.Murmur2Random;
```

Another approach might be to write create a `CustomPartitioner` class that would implement your preferred partitioning strategy to mimic your producers.